# Wordpress Polylang Translation of “Read More” and “Submit” button

Tags: wordpress, translation, polylang

I'm using Polylang on my clients website. They now have a blog, but the read more and submit button (for adding comments) are not translated into German. Also the title of the comment section is: Schreibe einen Kommentar, but my clients wants to change this into: Schreiben Sie einen Kommentar. Does anyone know how to do this?

I found this piece of code for the read more button on a [older StackOVerflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610135/polylang-string-translation-to-read-more-link-not-working):

```
function modify_read_more_link() {
  return  '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . pll__('read more') .  '</a>';
}

add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
pll_register_string('my-theme', 'read more');
```

It is showing up in the String Translations, but the translation is not working on the website. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong since I know very little JavaScript. I'm really stuck so I hope someone on here can help me out.

Thank you in advance!

Kind regards,
Michelle

Comment: Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
__('read more')
```

or

```
_e('read more')
```